# Long lived key/token based way to download google storage bucket objects with curl?

Tags: authentication, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

O.k. my fellow devops and coders.  I have spent the last week trying to figure this out with Google (GCP) Cloud Storage objects.  Here is my objective.

1. The solution needs to be light weight as it will be used to download images inside a docker image, hence the curl requirement.
2. The GCP bucket and object needs to be secure and not public.
3. I need a "long" lived ticket/key/client_ID.

I have tried the OAuth2.0 setup that Google's documentation mentions but everytime I want to setup an OAuth2.0 key it I do not get the option to have the "offline" access.  AND to top it off it requires you to put in source URL's that will be accessing the auth request.

Also Google Cloud Storage does not support the key= like some of their other services.  So here I have a an API KEY for my project as well as an OAuth JSON file for my service user and they are useless.

I can get a curl command to work with the temp OAuth bearer key but I need a long term solution for this.

```
RUN curl -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlsoB-ck37IIrXkvYVZLIr3u_oGB8e60UyUgiP74l4UZ4UkT2aki2TI1ZtROKs6GKB6ZMeYSZWRTjoHQSMA1R0Q9wW9ZSP003MsAnFSVx5FkRd9-XhCu4MIWYTHX" \
    -o "/home/shmac/test.tar.gz" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/mybucket/o/my.tar.gz?alt=media"
```

A long term key/ID/secret that will allow me to download a GCP bucket object from any location.

Answer (score 5):

> The solution needs to be lightweight as it will be used to download
>   images inside a docker image, hence the curl requirement.

This is a vague requirement. What is lightweight? No external libraries, everything written in assembly language, must fit in 1 KB, etc.

> The GCP bucket and object needs to be secure and not public.

This normal requirement. With some exceptions (static file storage for websites, etc) you want your buckets to be private.

> I need a "long" lived ticket/key/client_ID.

My advice is to stop thinking "long-term keys". The trend in security is to implement short-term keys. In Google Cloud Storage, seven-days is considered long-term. 3600 seconds (one hour) is the norm almost everywhere in Google Cloud.

For Google Cloud Storage you have several options. You did not specify the environment so I will include both user credentials, service account, and presigned-url based access.

**User Credentials**

You can authenticate with User Credentials (eg username@gmail.com) and save the Refresh Token. Then when an Access Token is required, you can generate one from the Refresh Token. In my website article about learning the Go language, I wrote a program on Day #8 which implements Google OAuth, saves the necessary credentials and creates Access Tokens and ID Tokens as required with no further "login" required. The comments in the source code should help you understand how this is done. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-and-go-my-journey-to-learn-a-new-language-in-30-days/#day_08

This is the choice if you need to use User Credentials. This technique is more complicated, requires protecting the secrets file but will give you refreshable long term tokens.

**Service Account Credentials**

Service Account JSON key files are the standard method for service-to-service authentication and authorization. Using these keys, Access Tokens valid for one hour are generated. When they expire new ones are created. The max time is 3600 seconds.

This is the choice if you are programmatically accessing Cloud Storage with programs under your control (the service account JSON file must be protected).

**Presigned-URLs**

This is the standard method of providing access to private Google Cloud Storage objects. This method requires the URL and generates a signature with an expiration so that objects can be accessed for a defined period of time. One of your requirements (which is unrealistic) is that you don't want to use source URLs. The max time is seven-days.

This is the choice if you need to provide access to third-parties to access your Cloud Storage Objects.

**IAM Based Access**

This method does not use Access Tokens, instead, it uses Identity Tokens. Permissions are assigned to Cloud Storage buckets and objects and not to the IAM member account. This method requires a solid understanding of how Identities work in Google Cloud Storage and is the future direction for Google security - meaning for many services access will be controlled on a service/object basis and not via roles that grant wide access to an entire service in a project. I talk about this in my article on [Identity Based Access Control](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-go-identity-based-access-control/)

**Summary**

You have not clearly defined what will be accessing Cloud Storage, how secrets are stored, if the secrets need to be protected from users (public URL access), etc. The choice depends on a number of factors.

If you read the latest articles on my website I discuss a number of advanced techniques on Identity Based Access Control. These features are starting to appear on a number of Google Services in the beta level commands. This includes Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Pub/Sub, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, Cloud KMS and soon more. Cloud Storage supports Identity Based Access which requires no permissions at all - the identity is used to control access.

Comment: John,  Awesome response and really appreciate the clarification.  It would seem there is no "long" lived token or key based way to access google cloud storage.  I did not think so but I wanted to check with the greater community if I was missing something.  Honestly I consider this a huge barrier to entry in the object storage market for Google, AWS and MS Azure can do this.

Comment: @shmac - There is a tradeoff between ease-of-use and security. I am more than happy to trade engineering man-hours to design more secure products. I am also an expert with AWS and Azure and we must do the same things to build robust secure applications on AWS and Azure. No matter which cloud vendor you chose, security becomes critical. Having a long-term key is a bandaid and not a solution.

Comment: It's not a bandaid if I have a use case that does not require that secure of a process in the first place.  In my use case I just want a more secure way to track which docker image is downloading which piece of software in a docker image.  I just solved this by making a public read-only bucket for my needs and will just use a standard 'curl' or 'wget' call.  On a side note I did put in a feature request to have Googles GSUTIL use keys WITHOUT the heavy requirements of the full gcloud SDK.

Comment: @shmac - This question has been answered. Please close this question. I can help you with technical answers/details. I cannot with the politics of why companies make decisions.